# xlst query to have grouping to only show 1 header for each value of select instead of multiple headers

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xlst query thats returning all the correct information i want from the xml raw data however because it has multiple objects it is returninf each result with its own headers but i only want 1 at the very start and not the others can anyone help me with the grouping. this is the xlst query:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CMDBSet">
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="">
<th>display label</th>
<th>root class</th>
<th>host servertype</th>
<th>host osreleasetype</th>
<th>host osinstalltype</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="CMDBObject/Properties">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="display_label"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="root_class"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="host_servertype"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="host_osrelease"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="host_osinstalltype"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and a snippet of the xml raw data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CMDBTopology>
<Objects>
<CMDBSet>
<name>80df0b42de8f31ac4cb7a30d325ff0c1</name>
<CMDBObject>
<identifier type="nt">80df0b42de8f31ac4cb7a30d325ff0c1</identifier>
<Properties>
<root_class type="STRING">nt</root_class>
<host_servertype type="STRING"></host_servertype>
<host_osrelease type="STRING"></host_osrelease>
<display_label type="STRING">pharsm-s3004</display_label>
<host_osinstalltype type="STRING"></host_osinstalltype>
</Properties>
</CMDBObject>
</CMDBSet>
<CMDBSet>
<name>8305e305bdaf613b50deab1da4ae469c</name>
<CMDBObject>
<identifier type="nt">8305e305bdaf613b50deab1da4ae469c</identifier>
<Properties>
<root_class type="STRING">nt</root_class>
<host_servertype type="STRING"></host_servertype>
<host_osrelease type="STRING">3790</host_osrelease>
<display_label type="STRING">phchbs-si442</display_label>
<host_osinstalltype type="STRING">Server Standard Edition</host_osinstalltype>
</Properties>
</CMDBObject>
```

I came across some possible way i could possibly achieve this like using a grouping like:

```
<xsl:key name="keyrootclass" match="diplaylabel" use="rootclass" />
<xsl:key name="keyhostservertype" match="displaylabel" use="hostservertype" />
<xsl:key name="keyhostosreleasetype" match="displaylabel" use="hostosreleasetype" />
<xsl:key name="keyhostservertype" match="displaylabel" use="hostservertype" />
```

but i am stuck on how to proceed as if i add these lines it wont output anything but without these keyname lines i get the output but with multiple header for each cmdbobject

Comment: It should be noted that the XSLT you posted is not valid XSLT and I'm guessing it doesn't even run. You have a `</body>` and `</html>` tag with no opening tag to go with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="">
            <th>display label</th>
            <th>root class</th>
            <th>host servertype</th>
            <th>host osreleasetype</th>
            <th>host osinstalltype</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates
             select="CMDBTopology/Objects/CMDBSet/CMDBObject/Properties" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Properties">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="display_label"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="root_class"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="host_servertype"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="host_osrelease"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="host_osinstalltype"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your provided input (after the missing tags are added), this produces the following output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="">
        <th>display label</th>
        <th>root class</th>
        <th>host servertype</th>
        <th>host osreleasetype</th>
        <th>host osinstalltype</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>pharsm-s3004</td>
        <td>nt</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>phchbs-si442</td>
        <td>nt</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>3790</td>
        <td>Server Standard Edition</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked thank you very much i was pulling my hair out for the last day and a half trying to work it out.